# traspose columns and row in r and extracting certain values

Tags: r

I'm new on R, so apologies in advance.
I have a data.frame (df_final_a) with 800+ columns and 16.000+ rows.
It looks like this:

```
**chrom gene mutation patient1 patient2 patient3**
 
  chr1   abc    xxx      ./.     0/1    ./. 
  chr1   def    yxx      1/1     ./.    0/1 
  chr2   ghi    yyx      0/1     ./.    ./. 
  chr2   lmn    yyy      ./.     1/1    ./.
```

./. = this means that the patient doesn't have that mutation.

0/1 and other numbers mean that the patient has a certain type of that mutation

From this data frame I want to have two other tables:

dfA:

```
    **patient    mutation**           

      patient1     yxx(1/1), yyx(0/1) 
      patient2     xxx(0/1), yyy(1/1)
      patient3     yxx(0/1)
```

dfB:

```
    **patient            chrom gene   mutation**

      patient2           chr1   abc     xxx       
      patient1, patient3 chr1   def     yxx        
      patient1           chr2   ghi     yyx        
      patient2           chr2   lmn     yyy
```

thank you for any suggestion you can give me

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can share code that generates your sample data, since in R there are various data formats and structures that will print out the same way. It also reduces ambiguity and saves others time. If you have `df_final_a`, you could run `dput(df_final_a[1:4, 1:6])` to create a code recipe that reproduces the first 4 rows and six columns of `df_final_a`, and include that code into your question.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the suggestion. I run what you wrote, this is the result: 
        
`structure(list(CHROM = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), symbol = c("PLEKHG5", 
"PLEKHG5", "PLEKHG5", "PLEKHG5"), exon = c("21/21", "21/21", 
"21/21", "21/21"), intron = c("", "", "", ""), hgvsc = c("c.*1440C>T", 
"c.*1413_*1420del", "c.*1379_*1382del", "c.*1333del"), hgvsp = c("", 
"", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000292992010d0>) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to work with this data if you reshape it into longer (aka tidy) format, with one row per observation of patient-chrom-gene-mutation. Then the two outputs you're looking for can each be made with a `group_by` and `summarize`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df_long <- df_final_a %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("patient"), names_to = "patient") %>%
  filter(value != "./.")  

dfA <- df_long %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  summarize(mutation = paste0(mutation, "(", value, ")", collapse = ", "))

#> dfA
## A tibble: 3 × 2
#  patient  mutation          
#  <chr>    <chr>             
#1 patient1 yxx(1/1), yyx(0/1)
#2 patient2 xxx(0/1), yyy(1/1)
#3 patient3 yxx(0/1) 


dfB <- df_long %>%
  group_by(chrom, gene, mutation) %>%
  summarize(patient = paste(patient, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  relocate(patient, .before = 1)

#> dfB
## A tibble: 4 × 4
#  patient            chrom gene  mutation
#  <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1 patient2           chr1  abc   xxx     
#2 patient1, patient3 chr1  def   yxx     
#3 patient1           chr2  ghi   yyx     
#4 patient2           chr2  lmn   yyy
```

---

Sample data

```
df_final_a <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             chrom = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2"),
              gene = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "lmn"),
          mutation = c("xxx", "yxx", "yyx", "yyy"),
          patient1 = c("./.", "1/1", "0/1", "./."),
          patient2 = c("0/1", "./.", "./.", "1/1"),
          patient3 = c("./.", "0/1", "./.", "./.")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)

tbl <- tribble(
  ~chrom, ~gene, ~mutation, ~patient1, ~patient2, ~patient3,
  'chr1',   'abc',    'xxx',      './.',     '0/1',    './.',
  'chr1',   'def',    'yxx',      '1/1',     './.',    '0/1', 
  'chr2',   'ghi',    'yyx',      '0/1',     './.',    './.', 
  'chr2',   'lmn',    'yyy',      './.',     '1/1',    './.'
)


(
  dfA <-
    pivot_longer(tbl, cols = starts_with("patient"),
                 names_to = "patient") |>
    filter(value != "./.") |>
    mutate(mutation = glue::glue("{mutation}({value})")) |>
    group_by(patient) |>
    summarise(mutation = paste(mutation, collapse = ", "))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   patient  mutation          
#>   <chr>    <chr>             
#> 1 patient1 yxx(1/1), yyx(0/1)
#> 2 patient2 xxx(0/1), yyy(1/1)
#> 3 patient3 yxx(0/1)


(
  dfB <-
    pivot_longer(tbl, cols = starts_with("patient"),
                 names_to = "patient") |>
    filter(value != "./.") |>
    group_by(chrom, gene, mutation) |>
    summarise(patient = paste(patient, collapse = ", ")) |>
    relocate(patient, .before = 1)
)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'chrom', 'gene'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   chrom, gene [4]
#>   patient            chrom gene  mutation
#>   <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 patient2           chr1  abc   xxx     
#> 2 patient1, patient3 chr1  def   yxx     
#> 3 patient1           chr2  ghi   yyx     
#> 4 patient2           chr2  lmn   yyy
```